# Displaying text within a vector icon

Tags: svg, react-native

I'm trying to build a custom play / stop button that displays dynamic text in its center. Currently, I'm using the `react-native-vector-icons` native module to render the icons. The icons I'm using are `play-circle-o` and `stop-circle-o` from the FontAwesome fonts library. Could someone guide me whether this is doable and how to proceed to accomplish this?

Answer (score 0):

You can use `position: 'absolute'` style attribute to position the text above the icon.